# Sort odd and even numbers in the same order that they appear

Tags: c, arrays

I've come across this: there is a given array which contains random numbers. I have to sort this array in such way that firstly I'll have the even numbers and then the odd ones in the exact order they appear.

For example input: 2,3,4,2,9,2,1,7,3  and output should be like: 2,4,2,2,3,9,1,7,3.

The thing is that I have to do this without any extra memory. If I didn't have this condition 2 different arrays for even/odd would have done the trick.

Any ideas?

EDIT: Ok, I must add that I'm a complete rookie.
Also, this is my *failed* attempt:

```
cin>>n;
for (i=0;i<n;i++)
    cin>>a[i];
for (i=0;i<n;i++)
{
    for (j=0;j<n;j++)
    {

        if (a[j]%2==1 && a[j+1]%2==0)
        {
            aux=a[j];
            a[j]=a[j+1];
            a[j+1]=aux;
        }
    }
}
for (i=0;i<n;i++)
    cout<<a[i]<<" ";
```

Comment: C and C++ are two different languages. Which are you using?

Comment: See [`std::stable_partition`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/stable_partition).

Comment: Then you shouldn't tag C++.

Comment: Until now I just used two different arrays and inserted the even numbers in the first one and the odd numbers in the second array. Then I just put them together

Comment: Use any stable sort with memory O(1) and for values use `value %2 ` ... as @P0W suggested. I dunno even bubble sort would work.

Comment: If not C++, those `cin`s and `cout`s don't make sense. (.. Is this pronounced "sin" and "kout"?)

Answer (score 1):

Do some stable sort, for example bubble or insertion sort, with a specially crafted comparision function, that will classify all even numbers equal, all odd numbers equal and any odd number <s>less</s> **greater** (thanks, @luk32) than any even number.

Comment: You mixed the ordering. Even numbers must be greater than odd ones to conform the example and the magic function is `modulo 2`, given that the default ordering is increasing, which i think is a default approach. Also not every stable sort will work. The memory constraint is important, though the examples you mention are O(1).

Comment: @luk32 Right, I've made the inverse ordering. The stable algorithm is an implication of requirement that 'the numbers are in the exact order they appear', and those which I mentioned are _in situ_. Of course one might choose some other alorithms, those two are, as noted, _for example_.

Answer (score 0):

It's fairly simple:

- Make an array the same size as the original.
- Pass across the first array copying the evens to the new array
- Pass across the first array copying the odds to the new array
- Change the pointer to point to the new array
- Delete the original array

Without extra memory...

- Starting at the second element check if it is even. If it is check the proceeding element if it is not. If not, swap. Store the location of the swap.
- Move up the array doing this until you do no more swaps.
- Done.

Comment: well the thing is that I must be doing all these things in the same array, I shouldn't create anything new

Answer (score 0):

To do this in place in a C array a fairly naive approach would work:

Scan through the array until you find an odd number, now scan forward until you find an even number and swap the two values.  Start scanning again from the next position.  When either scan reaches the end of the array your done.

This isn't a very effecient algorithm but it should work without allocating any extra memory.

Comment: That's a bubble sort! Hooray.

Comment: Yep - like I said not very effecient!

Comment: Time complexity was not a constraint. For me it's +1.

Answer (score 0):

One solution could be use `stack`. Whenever you get the odd number push it in `stack_odd` and similarly for even number pushed it in `stack_even`. This will also get you know the number of even and odd numbers. Now start filling the original array. And also make sure that which element you encountered first in order to fill the correct order of number in array..(i.e. if you encountered even number first start filling the original array by using`stack_even`.)

This will accomplished the task in `O(n)` time and `O(n)` space complexity.

Comment: A downvote might be because of using extra O(n) memory, while OP explicitly stated _'The thing is that I have to do this without any extra memory. If I didn't have this condition 2 different arrays for even/odd would have done the trick.'_ Just guessing...

Comment: @CiaPan oops i didn't read it completely i just jumped to give solution. :p

Answer (score 0):

The way I solved it was to find the index of the first odd element of the array and the index of the next even element in a loop.

Then rotate all the elements.

Something like

```
size_t firstodd, nexteven;
while (1) {
    firstodd = findfirstodd(arr, n);           // returns n when no odd element found
    if (firstodd == n) break;                  // no more changes needed
    nexteven = findnexteven(arr, n, firstodd); // returns n when no even element found
    if (nexteven == n) break;                  // no more changes needed
    rotate(arr, firstodd, nexteven);
}
```